# What is the difference between calling and caller method?

Tags: c#

I am so confused about calling and caller methods. I have read a book about c# exception handling. I have faced with words of calling and caller that I couldn't get it. Of course, I google it, and I found a link about calling and called, but again I didn't get it.

Unhandled Exception

> What happens if a try block throws an exception
>   and there is no corresponding catch handler? In the previous example,
>   it is possible that the lhsOperand text box could contain the string
>   representation of a valid integer but the integer it represents is
>   outside the range of valid integers supported by C# (for example,
>   “2147483648”). In this case, the int.Parse statement would throw an
>   OverflowException, which will not be caught by the FormatException
>   catch handler. **If this occurs and the try block is part of a method,
>   the method immediately exits and execution returns to the calling
>   method. If the calling method uses a try block, the runtime attempts
>   to locate and execute a matching catch handler for this try block. If
>   the calling method does not use a try block or if there is no matching
>   catch handler, the calling method immediately exits, and execution
>   returns to its caller, where the process is repeated. If a matching
>   catch handler is eventually found, the handler runs and execution
>   continues with the first statement that follows the catch handler in
>   the catching method.**

```
        private void calculateClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if ((bool)addition.IsChecked)
            {
                addValues();
            }
            else if ((bool)subtraction.IsChecked)
            {
                subtractValues();
            }
            else if ((bool)multiplication.IsChecked)
            {
                multiplyValues();
            }
            else if ((bool)division.IsChecked)
            {
                divideValues();
            }
            else if ((bool)remainder.IsChecked)
            {
                remainderValues();
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No operator selected");
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException fEx)
        {
            result.Text = fEx.Message;
        }
        catch (OverflowException oEx)
        {
            result.Text = oEx.Message;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ioEx)
        {
            result.Text = ioEx.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    private void addValues()
    {
        int lhs = int.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
        int rhs = int.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);
        int outcome = 0;

        outcome = lhs + rhs;
        expression.Text = $"{lhs} + {rhs}";
        result.Text = outcome.ToString();
    }

    private void subtractValues()
    {
        int lhs = int.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
        int rhs = int.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);
        int outcome = 0;

        outcome = lhs - rhs;
        expression.Text = $"{lhs} - {rhs}";
        result.Text = outcome.ToString();
    }

    private void multiplyValues()
    {
        int lhs = int.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
        int rhs = int.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);
        int outcome = 0;

        outcome = checked(lhs * rhs);
        expression.Text = $"{lhs} * {rhs}";
        result.Text = outcome.ToString();
    }

    private void divideValues()
    {
        int lhs = int.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
        int rhs = int.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);
        int outcome = 0;

        outcome = lhs / rhs;
        expression.Text = $"{lhs} / {rhs}";
        result.Text = outcome.ToString();
    }

    private void remainderValues()
    {
        int lhs = int.Parse(lhsOperand.Text);
        int rhs = int.Parse(rhsOperand.Text);
        int outcome = 0;

        outcome = lhs % rhs;
        expression.Text = $"{lhs} % {rhs}";
        result.Text = outcome.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: "Calling method" and "the caller" are just different turns of phrase that mean the same thing. There is no difference.

Comment: If method A calls B, and B calls C, and C calls D, then you have a chain A->B->C->D. The text in bold is saying that if D throws an exception, then its caller (the calling method; C) is expected to handle the exception. If it doesn't, then the exception bubbles up to the caller of C (the calling method; B), and so on, until the exception is caught or the application crashes.

Comment: Do you have a more specific question that would unblock you? From the title of the question it seems like you think that two things that are the same are different. If I say "the jogging person" and "the jogger" I mean the same thing. What are you really asking here? Do you understand what is meant by a "method call" in a programming language? Start with that.

Comment: Each method calling another method is the caller of that method.  This text is just saying that when the stack unwinds (because of an exception) each method's caller regains control when try catch is used. Look up stack unwind.

Comment: Also, I note that the descriptive text that you pasted down is a very much simplified version of what happens when an exception is encountered, possibly over-simplified. It would be both simpler and more accurate to say: (1) the runtime attempts to identify a catch block, possibly executing catch filters to do so; these filters run before any finally blocks (2) if a matching catch cannot be found, the program behaviour is implementation-defined,

Comment: (3) if a matching catch can be found then control passes to the nearest enclosing finally if there is one; we then must consider what happens if the finally throws; in that case we start over. If the finally does not throw before it completes normally then we continue on to the next finally if there is one. (4) Once there are no more finally blocks, control passes to the catch determined to be the appropriate handler.

Comment: That is also a big simplification of what really happens, but it is at least more accurate.

Comment: @EricLippert Thanks a lot you described it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translated by oozgul:

```
static void A()
{
    B();
    // When you invoke B() from inside A();
    // Calling method: A
    // Caller method: A
    // Called method: B
}

static void B()
{
    C();
    // When you invoke C() from inside B();
    // Calling method: B
    // Caller method: B
    // Called method: C
}
```

> If this occurs and the try block is part of C(), the method
>   immediately exits and execution returns to B().
>
> If B() uses a try block, the runtime attempts to locate and execute a
>   matching catch handler for this try block.
>
> If B() does not use a try block or if there is no matching catch
>   handler, B() immediately exits, and execution returns to A(),
>
> where the process is repeated.